# Question on Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $S=\{a_1,...,a_p\}$ is a finite subset of the compact interval $[a,b]$, and if the bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is such that $f(x)=0$ if $x\in[a,b]∼S$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and  $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$.

$[a,b]∼S$ refers to the complement of $S$ relative to $[a,b]$. 
$$[a,b]∼S=\{x\,|\,x\in[a,b],x\notin S\}$$
I would appreciate if someone could assist me  in helping me to understand the above question and how to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding some notation, one has $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i \right|\le \sum_{i=1}^n |f(\xi_i)|\Delta x_i\le2\,p\,k \,\|P\|$$ where $P=([x_{i-1},x_i],\xi_i)_{1\le i\le n}\,$ is a tagged partition of $[a,b]$ and $k=\max \{|f(a_1)|,\dots,|f(a_p)|\}$.

In fact the $a_1,\dots,a_p\,$ belong to the subintervals of $P$ not more than twice.

The conclusion is obvious.

The point is that the Riemann integral can be defined with the exception of a **finite** number of points; however you define the function at these points, you obtain the same value of the integral.$$$$